# Is it possible to specify the name of the .yml file for buildkite to use for its pipeline config?

Tags: buildkite

Buildkite by default searches in your repo for .buildkite/pipeline.yml, however I was wondering if its possible to specify an alternative name for the config file.

So for example is it possible to have the following folder and yml files in your repo:

```
.buildkite/pipeline.yml
.buildkite/pipeline2.yml
```

And then have one build pipeline search for the default ./buildkite/pipeline.yml and another build pipeline search for a specific ./buildkite/pipeline2.yml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few default paths, but you can also specify a path to the pipeline upload command, and this is a common pattern:

```sh
buildkite-agent pipeline upload .buildkite/pipeline-deploy.yml
```

See the docs for more info:

https://buildkite.com/docs/agent/v3/cli-pipeline#uploading-pipelines

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for.